# JVM Native Method Stack Architecture

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, stack, runtime

Does the Native Method Stack of the JVM have the same design as the Stack Area?
I know there is an entry per thread, but does the Native Method Stack also have stack frames and hold local variable references...etc? What I am trying to understand overall is if the two areas have the same design and function the same, then why not leverage the Stack Area for both... is it just a logical separation of duties?

Comment: This is entirely implementation defined. Each JVM implementation may choose how to handle Java and native frames, whether to share the same stack or not. As to HotSpot JVM, it do shares the same area for both purposes, see https://pangin.pro/posts/stack-overflow-handling

Comment: Perfect link ... along with the comment, it was more than what I was expecting, but exactly what I needed to get a solid grasp on some things.